# C# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages: Вывод данных json файла на страницу

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

Делаю проект на ASP.NET Core 2.2 (Razor Pages) в котором необходимо реализовать чтение json файла и вывод данных на страницу по средствам оператора foreach.
В интернете нашел пример на MVC и попытался с проецировать его на Razor Pages, но столкнулся со следующими проблемами:

1. В файле Index.cshtml.cs необходимо прописать путь к файлу json следующего вида "~/Product_catalog.json", но из этого ничего не получается. В настоящий момент работает конструкция:
   var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"C:\Users\OneDrive\Parsing_json\Parsing_json\wwwroot\Product_catalog.json");
   Но как я понимаю, после загрузки проекта на сервер эти пути станут не актуальны.
2. В этом же файле Index.cshtml.cs в строке с кодом: return View(countries); синтаксический анализатор выдаётся сообщение об ошибке "Имя View не существует в текущем контексте".
3. На странице html, файл Index.cshtml в строке с кодом: @foreach (var item in Model.countries) синтаксический анализатор выдаётся сообщение об ошибке "IndexModel не содержит определения countries, и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения countries принимающий тип IndexModel в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку)"
4. При отладке проекта Просматриваю содержимое переменной countries и почему то оно в виде ромбиков, хотя вся структура данных правильная. Как я понимаю дело в кодировке, но как это исправить ума не приложу.

Вторую неделю бьюсь с разными вариациями, пересмотрел множество подобных тем в интернете, но к сожалению примеров для Razor Pages найти не удалось.

Уважаемые эксперты прошу помочь в реализации данной задачи.
Спасибо.

К проекту подключен пакет NuGet: Newtonsoft.Json для сериализации данных json файла.

### **Код файла Index.cshtml.cs**

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Parsing_json.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"C:\Users\OneDrive\Parsing_json\Parsing_json\wwwroot\Product_catalog.json");
            var countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Countries>(json);
            return View(countries);
        }
        
        public class CountryData
        {
            public string Country { get; set; }
            public string[] States { get; set; }
        }
        public class Countries
        {
            public IList<CountryData> countries { get; set; }
        }
       
    }
}
```

### **Код файла Index.cshtml**

```html
@page
@model IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-light"></thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.countries)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Country)
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.States)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

### Содержимое файла Product_catalog.json следующего вида:

```js
{
  "countries": [
    {
      "country": "Страна1",
      "states": [ "Область1_1", "Область1_2", "Область1_3", "Область1_4" ]
    },
    {
      "country": "Страна2",
      "states": [ "Область2_1", "Область2_2", "Область2_3", "Область2_4" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: По пункту 3 - создайте свойство `IList<CountryData> countries { get; set; }` в `IndexModel` его там нет. По пункту 2 - `return view` там не нужен, присвойте результат в свойство `countries` которое создадите выше.

Comment: @Ruslan_K, спасибо.
Механизм понятен. но теперь вот на это countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json); синтаксический анализатор пишет - не удается неявно преобразовать тип "object" в "Sistem.Collections.Generic.IList<Parsing_json.Pages.IndexModel.CountryData>".
Существует явное преобразование (возможно, пропущено приведение типов).

Comment: укажите конкретный тип в который нужно преобразовать json `countries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CountryData>>(json);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ниже рабочее решение**
Благодарю за помощь участников ресурса Ruslan_K и @Pavel Krichevets[image: Результат работы приложения]

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections;

namespace Parsing_json.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public IList<CategoryData> Products { get; set; }

        public class CategoryData
        {
            public string Category { get; set; }
            public string[] Product { get; set; }
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"Product_catalog.json");
            Products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<CategoryData>>(json);
        }

    }
}
```

```html
@page
@model IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>

    <div class="container">
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-light"></thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Products)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h2>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
                            </h2>
                        </td>
                        @foreach (var s in item.Product)
                        {
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => s)
                            </td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

```js
[
  {
    "Category": "Категория_1",
    "Product": [ "Продукт_1_1", "Продукт_1_2", "Продукт_1_3", "Продукт_1_4" ]
  },
  {
    "Category": "Категория_2",
    "Product": [ "Продукт_2_1", "Продукт_2_2", "Продукт_2_3", "Продукт_2_4" ]
  }
]
```